# Convert flat array to nested parent-child format

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have an array with below format:

```
[{
    key: "a"
}, {
    key: "b"
}, {
    key: "c"
}, {
    key: "d"
}, {
    key: "e"
}]
```

Every element in the array is the parent of element next to it.

Required to convert it to below format:

```
[{
    key: "a",
    Nodes: [{
        key: "b",
        Nodes: [{
            key: "c",
            Nodes: [{
                key: "d",
                Nodes: [{
                    key: "e"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I have achieved this, but the logic I have implemented is quite lengthy and now I want to optimize code.

So I want to know the most optimized way to do this

Comment: What determines whether one object is a child of another?

Comment: Please show us your code so we can comment on it. How can we critique your method without seeing it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) makes this simple:

```js
const array = [{
  key: "a"
}, {
  key: "b"
}, {
  key: "c"
}, {
  key: "d"
}, {
  key: "e"
}];


const nested = array.reduceRight((Nodes, obj) => {
  if (Nodes) {
    return [Object.assign({}, obj, { Nodes })];
  } else {
    return [obj];
  }
}, null);

console.log(nested);
```

Comment: hey but Object.assign is not supported in Internet Explorer. can u suggest some other work-around, if yes please update your answer accordingly

Comment: Use a polyfill. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Comment: awesome knowledge @Aron